# Can't run any available OpenCL sample with recent API CL/cl2.hpp

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to get started with OpenCL. After installing it, I have found a little oddity compared to almost all online tutorials, there was no cl.hpp header, only cl2.hpp. I have learned that it is a new version. A new version of API with little to no tutorials available.

The tutorials I have found failed to compile. This one (http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/) for example failed to compile because of an undefined variable and if I avoided it, it reported that I had no OpenCL 2.0 devices. I was able to get this one past the device check (http://simpleopencl.blogspot.cz/2013/06/tutorial-simple-start-with-opencl-and-c.html), but it crashes when I try to create context (device was found).

Code I am trying:

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
if(all_platforms.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[0];
std::cout << "Using platform: "<<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<"\n";

//get default device of the default platform
std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
if(all_devices.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";


cl::Context context({default_device}); // null pointer read here

cl::Program::Sources sources;

// kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
std::string kernel_code=
        " void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){ "
        " C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)]; "
        " } ";
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});

cl::Program program(context,sources);
if(program.build({default_device})!=CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
    exit(1);
}

// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_B(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_C(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);

int A[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int B[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0};

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context,default_device);

//write arrays A and B to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,A);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,B);


//run the kernel
cl::KernelFunctor simple_add(cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add"),queue,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
simple_add(buffer_A,buffer_B,buffer_C);

//alternative way to run the kernel
cl::Kernel kernel_add=cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add");
kernel_add.setArg(0,buffer_A);
kernel_add.setArg(1,buffer_B);
kernel_add.setArg(2,buffer_C);
 queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
queue.finish();

int C[10];
//read result C from the device to array C
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,C);

std::cout<<" result: \n";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<C[i]<<" ";
}
```

I am using Intel Gen OCL Driver on Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a brief look, I don't see anything wrong with your code, nor do I believe the cl2.hpp is "broken", as I've been using that at work. You may need to set `CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION` to 120 (for example) if your CL driver doesn't support CL2.0.

Comment: I cannot set a lower version there, if I try, it reports that 'CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION must not be greater than CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION' and CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION is set to 200 in cl2.hpp.

Comment: Hmm, strange. cl2.hpp SHOULD support all versions of CL from 1.0 to 2.0 (at least). But maybe you need to set BOTH.

Comment: What do you mean with setting both? The software doesn't even have the v1 header (cl.hpp) included. It does have the cl.h header, but that one is suffering from the same problems.

Comment: Use `#define 'CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120` or something similar, before the `#include <CL/cl2.hpp>` - you should never have to use cl.hpp any longer, the cl2.hpp is a fully functional replacement, afaict.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Please reply to my question so that I could accept it.

Comment: I'm not quit sure but according to the [cl::Program Class Reference](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html) the `build ` function requires a `const vector< Device > &devices` or `const char *options=NULL`. I think in your code replacing `program.build({default_device})` with `program.build(all_devices)` should solve the problem. please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: The problem was solved ages ago and I no longer have that computer and I don't have problems on another one. I will try your solution if I get into problems on some other computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the driver doesn't support CL2.0, you need to "lower the expectation" of cl2.hpp by setting the minimum and target versions of CL to the relevant version (e.g. 1.2):

```
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
```

That way, the code inside cl2.hpp will compile for a CL1.2 environment.

Comment: If you know, please, where can one found an example of using OpenCL-CLHPP with opencl v1.2?

Comment: Sorry, don't know of an example.